# How to set the color in matplotlib 3d axis ax.plot_surface()?

Tags: matplotlib

How can I set the colors in a 3d surface plot? By default, the Z value is used to create a color, but that is encoding the same information twice and therefore redundant. I would like to embed some other information in the color dimension.

```
%matplotlib notebook

import seaborn as sns
sns.set_context('paper')
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D  # noqa: F401 unused import

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter
import numpy as np


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8), dpi=300)
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

# Make data.
X = peaks2d.index
Y = peaks2d.columns
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
Z = peaks2d.fillna(0).values.T

# Plot the surface.
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
xlabel('Retention Time')
ylabel('m/z')
title('Peak Selection')
```

[image]

I tried to use `color=(Z==0).astype(int)` but that did not work. It returned

> ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument: array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
>          [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
>          [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
>          ...,
>          [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
>          [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
>          [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]])

If a colormap is defined the function should be able to map integers to a color, but apparently this is not implemented?

Comment: You need to use the `facecolors` argument and supply a list of colors to it, as shown e.g. in [this example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/mplot3d/surface3d_3.html). Obviously, you can use a matplotlib colormap to generate this list of colors if you like.

Comment: It is not working really way, I think my data has a too high resolution for matplotlib.